# Can you restrict access to extensions?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect

I am currently developing an extension and am planning to release it to Magento Connect. Is there a way for me to restrict who can download the extension (restrict download ability to a few select stores) or can any store download it once it is on Connect?

Comment: Did you find any solution on your query Kevin?

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious once you put your extension to the Magento Connect, it will be available to all users. **Magento Connect is the public marketplace of magento**.

**What you can do is** write your extension to have `license system`. So that when people install your extension, they will need to provide license key, which will be provided by you and works with only one domain name.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the license system. Can I control whom I give this license?

Comment: Read this: http://inchoo.net/magento/license-for-local-project/. It should give you an idea.